# Rabbi Shimon without any other qualifiers

Tags: talmud-gemara, tractate-brachot, talmud-yerushalmi, tannaim

When there is a "Rabbi Shimon" without giving his father's name or his town, who is it assumed to be? The specific example I'm looking at is in [Yerushalmi Brachot Daf 25.-25:](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14139&st=&pgnum=50).

Comment: I think it's רשב"י.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Rashi Shavuos 2b - a bit more than halfway down](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9721&st=&pgnum=4&hilite=) says that Stam Rabbi Shimon is Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai

[Rashbam Bava Basra 102a - towards the bottom of the page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9585&st=&pgnum=207) also says that Stam Rabbi Shimon is Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai